# DXL code to copy Layout DXL value to Text attribute in DOORS module

Tags: ibm-doors

I am trying to copy a layout DXL value (Text) to another Text attribute in the same DOORS module. How can I copy this using DXL script?
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to recover the displayed text from your columns using the `text(column c, object o)` function *(Page 697 of the DXL 9.7 documentation)*. Just provide the function your DXL column, and then the object from which you want the text, and you should be good to go to copy this in an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to write as little code as possible and not having to worry about setting your view up correctly to do what Aubert suggested. You can first convert it to an Attribute DXL (Tools >> Support Tools >> Convert Layout DXL to Attribute DXL).

Then you can run something like this, make sure to replace the less/greater than signs (<>) and everything between it:

```
Object o
for o in entire(current Module) do
{
    o."<NAME OF TARGET ATTRIBUTE>" = o."<NAME OF NEW ATTRIBUTE DXL>""" // replace <>s too
}
```

I'm assuming the reason you want to copy it is because you want to keep specific versions of that DXL attribute?

Answer (score 0):

a really mundane method would be export the layout dxl to excel, make new text attribute in module, then import excel to new attribute.  no dxl needed.